# python telegram bot disallow nested conversations

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I am writing conversations with python-telegram-bot and need a way to disable nested conversations. That is, if a user is in a  conversation, then an entry command for another conversation should not activate another handler.

It seems that this is not enforceable in a ConversationHandler object. I.e. I try to catch a command in a state where I don't want another command to run (UPLOAD), but it doesn't work - a bot happily starts another conversation. Also, this does not work with fallbacks alone

```
submission_conv_handler = ConversationHandler(

        entry_points=[
             CommandHandler('submit', self.submit_command),
             
          ],


        states={
             self.CHOSE_TYPE: [
               CallbackQueryHandler(self.submission_query_callback, pattern=r'^(py|ipynb)')
             ],

             self.UPLOAD: [
               MessageHandler(Filters.document, self.upload_message),
               MessageHandler(Filters.command | Filters.text , done)
             ],

        },

        fallbacks=[MessageHandler(Filters.all, done)]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Interruption behaviour of conversations is a common problem, as PTB currently (v13.0) has no built in way to prevent it. Please have a look at the GitHub issues [1640](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/1640) and [1447](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/1447) as well as this [FAQ entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#can-i-check-if-a-conversationhandler-is-currently-active-for-a-user).

Answer (score 0):

When another conversation should be prevented for the user if the first one is not finished, looks like the only solution is still:

> There is no built-in way to do that. You can however easily set a flag
> as e.g. context.user_data['in_conversation'] = True in your
> entry_pointss and set it to False before returning
> ConversationHandler.END.